# calling python builtin dict on a mock

Tags: python, dictionary, mocking

I'd like to be able to setup a mock that allows me to return something when I apply the builtin `dict` method.

I've tried using `__iter__` to no avail.  I can't seem to get anything but an empty dictionary:

```
import mock
mocked_object = mock.MagicMock()
mocked_object.__iter__.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
dict(mocked_object)
# {}
```

Comment: What about `.return_value = iter([(1, 2), (3, 4)])`?

Comment: I still get an empty dictionary, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`dict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

> If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object. Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

`MagicMock` objects *expose* a `keys` method just because are mock objects and so `dict()` will consider they *mapping objects*. Unfortunately that way is little bit complicated to use if we want that on `dict` call mock become a dictionary with predefined key-values. The follow examples show how to implement a `dict` conversion to a predefined dictionary by use *mapping object* protocol:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> d = {"a":"A", "b":"B", "c":"C"}
>>> m.keys.return_value.__iter__.return_value = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> m.__getitem__.side_effect = ["A","B","C"]
>>> dict(m)
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}
>>> #Little bit generic
>>> m.keys.return_value.__iter__.return_value = d.keys()
>>> m.__getitem__.side_effect = lambda k:d[k]
>>> dict(m)
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}
```

Both are little bit hard to read and in our test we would like something of simpler to read.

To lead `dict` to use iterator instead mapping we can just remove `keys` method from our mock and set `__iter__.return_value`:

```
>>> del m.keys
>>> m.__iter__.return_value = [("a","A"),("b","B"),("c","C")]
>>> dict(m)
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}
>>> #Little bit generic
>>> m.__iter__.return_value = d.items()
>>> dict(m)
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}
```

IMHO that is a simple and neat way to set up your mock and get a predefined dictionary from `dict` call.

Comment: I would not recommend using the lambda function with a loop of dicts, it will only return the last dict.  You can simply say m.__getitem__.side_effect = d.__getitem__

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think you need to do something like this:

```
mocked_object.keys.return_value.__iter__.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
```

With this, the dict method will give you an object with those keys, and the result of `getattr(mocked_object, '1')` (so, another mocked method) as values. I think you might be able to do what you want by mocking the `keys()` method as well if you want more control on the result.

Comment: This works, thanks!  I do not understand how more mocked methods are set as values though..

Comment: Well I haven't dug that deep but I think that what the __dict__ method basically does is look for the object's attributes with keys(), then build a dict with those keys as attributes, and the attribute's value as values. Since the object is a mock, the value is a mocked method.